# Linking two Text Boxes so that changes in one text box causes change in another and vice versa.

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write a simple program in C# that performs conversion from kVA rating to kW rating and calculate Current ratings of a electricity generator at fixed voltage level and PowerFactor.

What the program would do is the user enter value in any of the three textboxes (let say kVA) and the program calculate other two parameters (kW and Current) in respective textbox without pressing any other button.

after that when the user changes the value of other two parameter (say kW) then program would recalculate kVA and Current.

Same with the current textbox.

Comment: You just need to create a TextChanged event handler for each textbox. The TextChanged event handler for one textbox would change the text of the other textbox.

Comment: If we are talking webforms I think javascript is more appropriate

Comment: @itsme86 Which would raise the textbox TextChanged event on the other, and again, and again, and never end :(

Comment: @Bun Unsubscribe the event handler for the other textbox before changing the text on it, then resubscribe it. `tb1.TextChanged -= tb1_TextChanged; tb1.Text = whatever; tb1.TextChanged += tb1_TextChanged;`

Comment: @itsme86 That`s just nasty though... :P

Comment: @Bun Well, the other option is using the KeyUp event and when a certain key is pressed, or a certain amount of inactivity goes by, update the other textbox.

Comment: @itsme86 You should post that KeyUp comment as an answer :)

Comment: @Bun Thanks alot. Unsubscribe/subscribe method worked. I didnt know about this feature earlier. Thanks everyone who commented on this post.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

On Form Load:

```
Textbox1.KeyUp += ProcessChange;
Textbox2.KeyUp += ProcessChange;
```

Then the ProcessChange handler:

```
private void ProcessChange(object sender, KeyEventArgs ka)
{
   if(sender == Textbox1)
   {
      //do work...
   }

   else //sender==Textbox2
   {
      //do work...
   }
}
```

This should get you going in the right direction...